# Implement a list with section divider in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi how can i implement a list with section divider like the one on android's [building blocks lists](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html)

[image]

Can you point any articles or tutorials to achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

I implemented a possible version here:

http://steprobe.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/google-building-blocks-style-listview-for-android/

Comment: This answer should be accepted ! clearly explained how to control dividers !!

Answer (score 3):

There are many tutorials to get grouped lists. The trick is to look for ["adapter"](https://www.google.es/search?q=developers%20blog%20android%20listview&oq=developers%20blog%20android%20listview&sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=es&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=android%20header%20adapter&oq=android%20header%20adapter&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30l2j0i8i10i30j0i8i30.72309.75269.0.75394.22.22.0.0.0.1.385.2474.12j7j1j1.21.0...0.0...1c.1.d4wFVyGhY-8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=87805ab6cf109624&bpcl=38897761&biw=1366&bih=617) and not "list". For instance, this one: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440

Comment: since it is shown on the android website i assume there is an adapter that does it? if you can point it out i will be very grateful!

Comment: Yes. Long story short, the listview request the adapter the views for the currently visible items, and the adapter, through its getView() method, returns what must be displayed on screen. It also allows to have different types of views returned in that method, which is what will allow you to have those "headers". I recommend you to take a look at the presentations of Romain Guy in the Google I/Os (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) regarding the ListView component

Answer (score 1):

Each row in your list can be totally separated in terms of layout from others. So if you got 3 rows on your list, you can have each one can look totally different. You need to write your own adapter (i.e. extending ArrayAdapter), override `getView()`, `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`. Then for each row your `getView()` shall do any logic you  want, inflate any layout you want and return that View to the list.